How to omit the outer braces around an implicit options hash in Rubocop?
Rubocop does not swear at code where a hash with parentheses is passed to the method parameter, for example:
user.set({ name: 'John', age: 45, permissions: { read: true } })

I would like him to consider only such lines as correct:
user.set(name: 'John', age: 45, permissions: { read: true })

I found this issue.
Does this mean that I will not be able to configure rubocop for this?

Not an expert on Rubocop but there are cases where omitting the curly braces results in invalid code.

Since the keyword arguments changes in ruby 2.7 and 3.0, the 2 are no longer equivalent.
Sometimes the curly braces are required for the method to understand the arguments correctly.
Example:
def foo(x = {}, y: 1)
  puts x.inspect
  puts y.inspect
end

foo({y: 2}) # {:y=>2}; 1
foo(y: 2) # {}; 2

This is why the option was removed from Rubocop in the issue that you found and why it is unlikely to be re-added.
